# Blazor - Trying to format a textarea with new lines

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I have a simple textarea:

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" rows="20" cols="40" style="resize: both;  overflow: auto; ">
   @reportText
</textarea>
```

I am trying to update that text area based on a button pressed:

```
    {
        userReport = await DataService.GetUserReport(user);
        foreach (Insider2.Data.Report r in userReport)
        {
            reportText += ((MarkupString)"<br>");
            reportText += r.Data.Trim();
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Nothing I do seems to work when it comes to adding a += "\r\n"
injecting ""
Etc...

Anything I try just gets rendered as text in the text area. I really need to figure out how to put formatting in the box (new lines).

Secondly, even if I call .trim() on the values going into the text area, I seem to get really weird spaces and new lines in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to integrate the following into your code

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering

<div class="form-group-sm">
    <label class="control-label">Message</label>
    <textarea rows="4" value="@EmailMessage" @onchange="@((args) => EmailMessage = args.Value.ToString())" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>

@code {
    private string emailMessage = "Test Email text \r\nline two \r\n line 3";// "<p class='markup-string-value'>This is a <em>markup string</em>.</p>";

    public string EmailMessage
    {
        get => emailMessage;
        set
        {
            if (emailMessage != value)
            {
                emailMessage = ((MarkupString)value).ToString();
            }
        }

    }

   }
```

Note: You can use either the value attribute ( which is not supported in HTMl) or the content of the textarea.